# Rails: Cleaning up large methods in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

Still learning how to refactor some of my controllers and would like some advice (I left some notes in the code block as to what's going on).

My current implementation works OK, but I'm wondering if there is a better & easier way to approach this; something about adding this many instance variables in the method to pull off such a trivial thing.

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    ## records created through app that have been approved (published)
    @paid_jobs = Job.published

    ## records fetched from RSS feed
    @fetched_jobs = JobEntry.all

    ## creates an array of paid_jobs and fetched_jobs, and what is considered the 'feed'. would usually be order("published_at DESC") but you can't call order on an array
    @job = (@paid_jobs + @fetched_jobs).sort_by(&:published_at).reverse

    ## you can't show pagination links for a static array directly. you can, however, first paginate it
    @jobs = @job.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    ## this is the actual variable I call in the Job#index view lol
    @published_jobs = @jobs.group_by { |job| job.published_at.to_date }
  end
```

Comment: If you only need `@published_jobs` in the view, then all other variables can be local (i.e. remove the `@`). Better yet, you could create a new class that handles all the logic and just return `published_jobs`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gerry...in terms of making it easier to read, moving them to a new class seems smart.

Comment: Can you think of a better way to combine the two relation objects (@paid_jobs + @fetched_jobs)?

Comment: Why would you combine those? They are objects of different classes.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I need to display a feed that consists of those two objects, paid_jobs & fetched_jobs

Comment: You could run a backend service that fetches all the RSS feed jobs, and creates actual Job records. This way you don't have to deal with two types of objects. I think the controller shouldn't be bothered with the fact that the jobs are obtained from multiple sources. Maybe run some kind of Cronjob.

Comment: Another idea could be to create a new CombinedJob model (that might inherit from Job), for which you write an all method, that first calls `super` and then fetches all the JobEntry records.

Comment: I'd move it all (except paginating) to Job or JobEntry class method

Comment: A new class would definitely help, because the combination of the two classes is a different kind of thing. You can also place sorting routines in it, and later refactor without affecting the class's interface. I would also experiment with sorting the two sources of records prior to adding them together, to see if it can improve overall performance – the database-backed Job class is otherwise likely to return in something close to completely the opposite of the sorting that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the rails feature single table inheritance (STI). This lets you store similar models in one table,so you could store the regular jobs and the fetched job in one table. Selection and pagination would now be very simple and removes all needs for any custom logic in ruby. This might also speed up your performance significantly (depending on the number of database records).

See the official docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance

So you would create the parent class:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) } # is inherited by all children
  scope :latest, -> { order(published_at: :desc) } # shortcut for ordering
  # you can add more scopes to enhance readability in controller

  # Job related logic inherited by all children
end
```

It is important that the table for this AR has the column `type` (string).

Then you derive both job types from that parent class:

```
class InternalJob < Job
  # InternalJob related logic
end

class FetchedJob < Job
  # FetchedJob related logic
end
```

Now you can fetch all the jobs to your hearts desire and paginate on it:

```
InternalJob.published # returns all published internal Jobs
FetchedJob.published # returns all published internal Jobs
Job.published # returns all Jobs
```

pagination and sorting is easy:

```
Job.published.sort_by(&:published_at).reverse.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

This would scale very well as the database does all the filtering and sorting.

This also makes your controller code very slim:

```
def index
  @published_jobs = Job.published.latest.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).group_by do |job|
    job.published_at.to_date
  end
end
```

Comment: I would recommend changing `latest` to `{order(published_at: :desc)}` so that the ordering is placed on SQL and the scope is chainable. Right now I think this will raise an Error since the scope does not return an ActiveRecord::Relation object as expected.

Comment: Oh, @mbuechmann this looks great. Going to give it a try later this evening and I'll report back...

Comment: Lol @mbuechmann this is so much better dude. Good approach to remain DRY as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try below methods to clean your code

1. Go for ActiveJob for fetching the records in background
2. Use ActiveSupport::Concern to keep helper methods for controller in another file. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html
3. Or you can keep cron job using Active Job and store result in json format